# Strong parameter does not work when i new model and controller in spree '3-0-stable' and rails 4.2

Tags: spree, strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.2

How to add new fields for spree::pre_order in Spree-3.0 + Rails4 ?

Like my old customization: ==========================

**app/Controllers/spree/api/pre_order_controller**

class PreOrderController < Spree::Api::BaseController

```
def create
    @pre_order = PreOrder.new(pre_order_params)
    if @pre_order.save
    end
    respond_with(@pre_order)
end

private
def pre_order_params
  params.require(:pre_order).permit(:user_id,:is_order_created)

end
```

end

**I Got following Error**

**{
    "exception": "param is missing or the value is empty: pre_order"
}**

Please let me know your comments.